# JS Array map function, cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a complex JS array of objects and properties. Some of them return value but some return null, the problem is when I am mapping through the list it causes error whenever there is a null value.

I cannot filter out the array right now because I am already inside a loop and should not create another filtered array. What would my best approach be? I want my loop to return Array.Group.name[0].text and if it is not there just return null.

```
const x = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "Groups": [
          {
            "name": [
              {
                "language": "en-US",
                "text": "REGULAR_TIME"
              }
            ],
            "isSystem": true
          },
          {
            "name": [
              {
                "language": "en-US",
                "text": "CHARGEABLE"
              }
            ],
            "isSystem": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "Groups": [
          {
            "name": [
              {
                "language": "en-US",
                "text": "REGULAR_TIME"
              }
            ],
            "isSystem": true
          },
          {
            "name": [
              {
                "language": "en-US",
                "text": "CHARGEABLE"
              }
            ],
            "isSystem": true
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
      
      x.map(y=>y.Groups.name[0].text)
      
      console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Groups` is an array too, so you have to use indexes to access its members like `Groups[0]`. It is not clear the name of what `Groups` element you want to get though.

Probably, you meant  `x.map(y=>y.Groups[0].name[0].text)`

`Groups` being an array is an object too. so `Groups.name` gives you nothing since such a property isn't present.

```js
let x = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "Groups": [
          {
            "isSystem": true
          },
          {
            "name": [
              {
                "language": "en-US",
                "text": "CHARGEABLE"
              }
            ],
            "isSystem": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "Groups": [
          {
            "name": [
              {
                "language": "en-US",
                "text": "REGULAR_TIME"
              }
            ],
            "isSystem": true
          },
          {
            "name": [
              {
                "language": "en-US",
                "text": "CHARGEABLE"
              }
            ],
            "isSystem": true
          }
        ]
      }
      ];
      
      
      console.log(x.map(y => y.Groups[0].name?.[0].text));

      // or just filter the absent names out before the main routine.
      console.log(x.filter(y => y.Groups[0].name).map(y => y.Groups[0].name?.[0].text));
```

Comment: x.map(y=>y.Groups[0].name[0].text    Yes, this is the exact data I am trying to get and I have this error. So how would I access the elements when Groups.name is not available?

Comment: I added an example when `name` is not present. It gives just undefined in the final result, but you can implement any value through `if` check in `map` callback.

Comment: @WildThing also I added beforehand filtering to get just elements where `name` property is present.

Answer (score 1):

here is the problem !
`Groups` is an array so :

```
let result = [];
  for (i=0; i<x.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<x[i].Groups.length;j++){
      result.push(x[i].Groups[j].name[0].text)
    }
  }
```

this loop returns a result that contains an array of text

or you can try this :

```
x.forEach(el=>{
    el.Groups.forEach(v=>{
      result.push(v.name[0].text)
    })
  })
```